# Time series vs Cross section data doubt

Tags: regression, dataset

I have been reading Basic Econometrics by Gujarati and I came across certain inconsistencies. 
In the chapter, Population census has been mentioned as a time-series data, and further, in another paragraph as cross-section data too. 
In the MCQs after every chapter, Population census has been marked as Cross-section data only.

I wonder - under which category does Population Census fall? My own opinion is that it falls under Cross section data as data is collected only at one point of time. 
What is the actual answer?

Answer (score 1):

The data from one Census is cross-sectional data. For example data from future 2020 USA Census.

But if putting the data from several censuses together, you get a time series type data.For example, the population from censuses since 1790 in USA.

Comment: From what I can infer, the book is referring to data from one census. Thanks for your answer. Do you then think it was a mistake for them to tag it under time series data as well?

Comment: I am not familiar with questions asked in Census. It is possible the historical data are collected in census, such as the household income in last year, .... Then you get the time series data. If Census does not collect the historical data, it is absolutely cross-sectional.